# How to change the font size of Chip of Material-UI

Tags: javascript, css, material-ui

I have `Chip` widget

```
const styles = {
  root:{
  },
  chip:{
    margin: "2px",
    padding: "2px"
  }
}

const SmartTagChip = (props) =>{
  const classes = useStyles();
  return(  
    <Chip style={{color:"white"}} clickable className={classes.chip}
    color="default" 
     label={item.label} variant="outlined"/>:
  )
}
```

I want to make font size bigger.

So I try but in vain.

```
<Chip style={{color:"white"}} clickable className={classes.chip}
```

I am reading document `https://material-ui.com/api/chip/`

and found some information about `CSS`

```
root    .MuiChip-root   Styles applied to the root element.
```

I guess I should customize `.MuiChip-root` class though,

How can I do this?

Comment: Try using custom CSS along with !important as a flag at the end of your CSS property. It has the highest CSS Specificity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use built-in solution from Material-ui called [withStyles](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/). It allows to simply apply styles to components.
In your case it will look like this:

```js
const StyledChip = withStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: 'red'// here you can do anything actually 
  },
  label: {
    textTransform: 'capitalize',
  },
})(Chip);

const SmartTagChip = (props) =>{
  const classes = useStyles();
  return(  
    <StyledChip clickable
    color="default" 
     label={item.label} variant="outlined"/>:
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a style class for the chip and then access the label through a sub-selector.

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
    
myClassName: {
    borderRadius: '9px', //some style
    '& .MuiChip-label': { fontSize: 18 }, // sub-selector
  },

}));
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete Sabrina's answer

```
import {makeStyles} from "@mui/styles";

    
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
        chipCustom: {
            borderRadius: '9px', //some style
            '& .MuiChip-label': {fontSize: 18}, // sub-selector
        },
    }));
    
const customChipClass = useStyles();
    
<Chip className={customChipClass.chipCustom} label="Test"/>
```